# create a custom tab bar to have a circular indicator below the active tab bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a custom tab bar in flutter in which an active tab bar will have a circular indicator below the tab title. this tab bar is inside the body of the scaffold and I want a flutter code to achieve this functionality. I have an image [image: here]

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can reproduce what you want by following this tutorial : https://divyanshu.dev/building-custom-tabbar-indicator-in-flutter-37a93c0fceff

Comment: i have gone through this article but i was not able to implement it.  i need a code so that i can use it

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce step by step the tutorial ? Which step have you difficulties with ? Can you update your questions with code snippets that you are struggling to debug ?

Comment: I have followed the step by step tutorial. but the issue I  am facing is when user clicks on the tab a grey color box appears for a second. I do not want to have this.

Comment: Can you show your code so i can help you make this box dissapear

Comment: i have followed the article and in tabbar indicator property i called the DotIndicator class as:
'TabBar(
            indicator: DotIndicator(),
            tabs: [
              Tab(child:Text("Details")),
              Tab(child:Text("Menu")),
            ],
          ),'

Comment: If you edit your original post with your whole class code and a screenshot of the result so that we can see what exactly is wrong that would be good. Just with this few code, this is impossible to help you.